# datatool writes renewcommand instead of updating it

Tags: datatool, database

In my MWE I want to update a command via `\renewcommand`, but instead `datatool` writes my updated command to the output. In addition my `\ifthenelse` seems to be always true and therefore execute the "then" instruction and never the (empty) "else" instruction.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{eurosym}
%\usepackage{isodate}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcommand{\usection}[1]{% unnummeriertes Unterkapitel mit Eintrag ins Inhaltsverzeichnis
    \phantomsection % fix für hyperref
    \section*{#1} % unnummeriertes Unterkapitel
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1} % Eintrag ins Inhaltsverzeichnis
}

\newcommand{\Test}{}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{testfile.csv}
    
    Projekt,    Kunde
    P1,         K1
    P2,         K2
    P3,         K2
    P4,         K1
    
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    
\tableofcontents
    
\DTLloaddb{data}{testfile.csv}

\chapter{Kunden}

\DTLsort[Error]{Kunde}{data}

\DTLforeach%
{data}% database name
{\Kunde=Kunde, \Projekt=Projekt}% assignments
{% what to do at each iteration
    \ifthenelse{ % Conditions
        \equal{\Test}{} % Condition 1
        \OR % ODER Schaltung
        {\NOT{\equal{\Test}{\Kunde}}}} % Condition 2
    {\usection{\Kunde} % then
        {}} % else
    \renewcommand{\Test}{\Kunde} % Test neu definieren
    
    \begin{table}[!h]
        \begin{tabular}{lr}
            \toprule
            Kriterium & Wert\\
            \midrule
            Projekt & \Projekt \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: As your code is rather hard to comprehend it might be an idea to you to explain what the expected outcome your be and what exactly you get right now

Comment: For each customer (= Kunde) I want to write a seperate ```\usection``` (but only once for each customer, that's why there is the ```\ifthenelse``` condition in the cycle). The table is what I want to write for each customer on a per project base.

Currently it writes a ```\usection``` in each cycle and in addition the ```\renewcommand``` writes the current ```\Kunde``` (so the same data as the usection directly before it) in the file instead of just updating the ```\Test``` command with the new customer.

Comment: @Lukas What you want to do is still unclear to me (esp. your way of handling a client only once, since the various `K1` instances aren't contiguous in your CSV file). But one thing is clear: your curly braces aren't correctly placed: the *then* clause is `\usection{\Kunde} {}` and  the *else* clause is `\renewcommand`. Therefore, `\ifthenelse` always executes the *then* clause and eats the *else* clause; there remains `{\Test}{\Kunde}` in the input stream, which typesets the expansion of `\Test` (empty) and of `\Kunde` (the client name). Just as you experienced. :-)

Comment: @frougon: as they are not contiguous I need to sort the customers/clients, which I do with `\DTLsort` right before I cycle through the database with `\DTLforeach`. Regarding the not correctly placed braces: I will have a look at it, thanks for the hint!

Comment: Ah, okay, I had not paid attention to the sort. Otherwise, with `expl3`, it's trivial to see if some particular token list is a member of a given sequence of token lists (a `seq` variable). And LaTeX2e has `\in@`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problem is that your curly braces aren't correctly placed: the *then* clause is `\usection{\Kunde} {}` and the *else* clause is `\renewcommand`. Therefore, `\ifthenelse` always executes the *then* clause and eats the *else* clause; there remains `{\Test}{\Kunde}` in the input stream, which typesets the expansion of `\Test` (empty) and of `\Kunde` (the client name).

Once this is fixed, you have a second problem: after TeX has executed `\renewcommand{\Test}{\Kunde}`, the replacement text of `\Test` is *a single token,* which is the control sequence token `\Kunde`. This is useless to “remember” the last client seen, because when the next iteration starts, `\Test` still contains the only control sequence token `\Kunde` (whose meaning may have changed), not the name of the previously seen client, which is now inaccessible.

I removed the use of `ifthen` because the `\equal` test recursively expands tokens, which is likely to cause problems here in case some client names contain non-expandable markup. Instead, I used `\ifx`.

Also, since the `\DTLforeach` loop doesn't attempt to modify the underlying database here, one can use `\DTLforeach*` instead, which is faster than `\DTLforeach`.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{datatool}

\newcommand{\usection}[1]{% unnummeriertes Unterkapitel mit Eintrag ins Inhaltsverzeichnis
    \csname phantomsection\endcsname % fix for hyperref, if loaded
    \section*{#1}% unnummeriertes Unterkapitel
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}% Eintrag ins Inhaltsverzeichnis
}

\newcommand{\Test}{}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{testfile.csv}

    Projekt,    Kunde
    P1,         K1
    P2,         K2
    P3,         K2
    P4,         K1

\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mytest}{%
  \ifx\Test\empty
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \else
    \ifx\Test\Kunde
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@gobble
    \else
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@firstofone
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\DTLloaddb{data}{testfile.csv}

\chapter{Kunden}

\DTLsort[Error]{Kunde}{data}

\DTLforeach*
{data}% database name
{\Kunde=Kunde, \Projekt=Projekt}% assignments
{%
  \mytest{%
    \usection{\Kunde}%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\Test\expandafter{\Kunde}%
  }%
%
  \begin{table}[!h]
    \begin{tabular}{lr}
        \toprule
        Kriterium & Wert\\
        \midrule
        Projekt & \Projekt \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## The `\mytest` macro

The usage of this macro is `\mytest{...}` and we want this to expand to:

- `...` when this is a new client (i.e., either `\Test` is empty, or it's different from `\Kunde`);
- the empty token list otherwise.

The easiest way to do this is to cause `\mytest` to expand to `\@firstofone` in the first case and to `\@gobble` in the second case. Note that the expansion of `\@firstofone` will remove the outer braces in `{...}`, which is important (otherwise, the redefinition of `\Test` wouldn't last long enough, as it is local). So, let's see how it goes:

```
\ifx\Test\empty
  \expandafter\@firstofone
\else
  \ifx\Test\Kunde
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
\fi
```

If `\Test` is empty, the first test is true and what remains in the input stream right after the test outcome has been determined is (without any space before the `\expandafter`):

```
  \expandafter\@firstofone
\else
  ⟨contents of the else clause⟩
\fi
```

When TeX expands the `\expandafter`, this expands the `\else` which removes everything up to, and including, the last `\fi` (because the `\ifx` test was true). What then remains in the input stream before `{...}` is `\@firstofone`, which is exactly what we wanted because `\@firstofone{...}` becomes `...` after one expansion step.

Now, let's see what happens when the first `\ifx` test is false. TeX skips tokens (respecting `\iffoobar...\fi` nesting) until it finds the matching `\else`, and removes this `\else`. This leaves the following in the input stream (without any space before the `\ifx`):

```
  \ifx\Test\Kunde
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
\fi
```

What we want is to leave either `\@gobble` or `\@firstofone` depending on whether `\ifx\Test\Kunde` is true or false. Suppose the test is true (same client as previously seen). Let's also assume that we didn't put the first `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter` in the code. TeX would then see what follows before the `{...}` in the input stream:

```
                                        \@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
\fi
```

This wouldn't work at all, because `\@gobble` would eat the next token, which is `\else`! And then TeX would go on with the remaining `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@firstofone\fi\fi`, which would soon leave `\@firstofone` in the input stream instead of the desired `\@gobble` (you'll understand why in a minute).

So, I put the `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter` before `\@gobble`. The first `\expandafter` jumps over the second one and expands the third one, then disappears—that is its job. Since the third `\expandafter` is being expanded, it jumps over `\@gobble`, expands the following token (an `\else`), then disappears. The expansion of `\else` removes all tokens (respecting `\iffoobar...\fi` nesting) up to and including the matching `\fi`: the one after `\@firstofone`. The first and third `\expandafter`s have now been expanded, and thus have disappeared. What remains in the input stream before `{...}` is therefore:

```
\expandafter\@gobble
\fi
```

That's easy: TeX expands the `\expandafter`, which causes it to disappear after having caused the `\fi` to expand, which caused it to disappear too. So, there remains only `\@gobble`, then our `{...}` code. This is exactly as desired, since `\@gobble{...}` expands to the empty token list (in one step).

Let's step back a little bit and consider an arbitrary stream of tokens represented by `◆`. If you think about it, `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\onetoken◆` becomes `\expandafter\onetoken❶` after one expansion step, where `❶` is the first-level expansion of `◆`. After two expansion steps, `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\onetoken◆` therefore leaves `\onetoken❷` in the input stream, where `❷` is the second-level expansion of `◆`.

So, after two expansion steps, `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\onetoken◆` becomes `\onetoken` followed by the second-level expansion of `◆`. This is very useful, you should remember it.

The last case of our `\mytest` macro is similar: if the `\ifx\Test\Kunde` test is false, after skipping tokens up to and including the matching `\else`, TeX has the following tokens in the input stream before our `{...}` (without any space before the `\expandafter`):

```
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
\fi
```

The three `\expandafter`s are used to get rid of the two `\fi`s by expanding them. Then there remains only `\@firstofone` before our `{...}` and, as we've already seen, `\@firstofone{...}` expands to `...` (in one step).

In our document, `...` stands for the following:

```
\usection{\Kunde}%
\expandafter\def\expandafter\Test\expandafter{\Kunde}%
```

Comment: thanks for your help! As I am not yet very well in terms of LaTeX syntax, could you please elaborate/explain why all these  `\expandafter`s, `\@firstofone` and `\@gobble` are needed/used?

Comment: This is difficult to explain without some basic knowledge of how TeX processes its input stream of tokens and how `\expandafter` and the `\ifx` test work. I've done my best. If this isn't enough, I suggest to read the TeXbook, especially its chapter 20 (on macros).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, it helped me a lot!

Comment: Thanks, glad to hear that.